# Calling a C# webservice from the Success function of another Webservice?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services

My question is simple.  Can you call a C#  webservice from the Success function of another webservice?  I think that the answer is no.

I have a login webservice which is called when a user tries to do something that requires the user to be logged in.  This then calls another webservice, when the action is complete it does not go into the onSuccess function.  I am assuming that it is not able to do so?  Is this correct?

Example code, not actual code.

```
webservice.login(onLoginSuccess)

function onLoginSuccess(){

    webservice.doSomething(onDoSomethingSuccess)

}

function onDoSomethingSuccess(){

    .... does not get here.

}
```

This is the code to it's bare bones.

On client JavaScript call, success of login webservice.

```
function onLoginSuccess(result){


    negotiateWithUser(true,
                      activeUser.id,
                      negotiation.dateID,
                      activeUser.showChat,
                      true);
}


function negotiateWithUser() {

    <code>

    if (justLoggedIn) updateDateData();

    <code>
}

 function updateDateData(){
     if (populate==false){

         populate=true;       
        WebService.Negotiations.DatesGet(activeUser.id,SucceededtoCallbackDateRefresh, ErrorHandler);          
     }
}
```

Does not go into the function SucceededtoCallbackDateRefresh even though data is returned and there are no errors.

I think I know what the problem is, in the negotiateWithUser function the updateDateData is called, execution control is given back to the negotiateWithUser function instead of going into the SucceededtoCallbackDateRefresh success funtion, as it is an asynchronous call.  I think some kind of callback function is required.

I have got round the problem by calling the updataDateData function in a setInterval() in the onLoginSuccess function instead.

```
 function onLoginSuccess(result){ 

      if (negotiate) {              
           timerInterval = setInterval("updateDateData()", 300);
      }

 }
```

It works. If someone has a more graceful approach, I would be very interested.
Thanks.

Comment: You *can*. That doesn't necessarily make it a good idea. Tread carefully :)

Comment: Thanks David but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Well, you mentioned that wasn't your actual code, so I didn't get too specific in commenting about it. If it isn't working the first thing I'd suggest is making sure your references to the services are all right - if you posted a more representative snippet it might be helpful.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work for me" could use a little more detail, errors shown, more code, etc...

Comment: The question is a bit confusing esp. since you've tagged JavaScript.  Service to Service calls are fine within C#.  If something is failing in your code, it may be best to post the actual code so we can help.

Comment: That's pretty much it.  It is called from the client side, that's why I have included JavaScript. There are no errors. I have stepped through the server side C# code and it returns but does not go into the onSuccesss function as it does when the user is logged in.

Comment: So this is representative of the javascript calling the code, not the service itself? We'd need to see the service code as well. And how this javascript actually invokes the service, presumably (eventually) an ajax call of some sort. There are just too many unknowns here to be very helpful.

Comment: Ok. thanks for your comments.  I will include the code later, if you think that it will make it any clearer.  It doesn't use an Ajax call in the classic sense. ASP.net creates a proxy stub which you can use on the client to call  a method of the webservice directly.

Comment: But that javascript proxy stub still has to make a call back to the service - the runtime may build a layer of indirection on it, but either way if it's being called in the context of a page, eventually, somewhere, buried deep in the dark of all the slathered layers of stuff ASP.NET puts atop itself, there almost certainly lurks an ajax call :) :)

Comment: Too true but it is completely abstracted which is the way I like it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

How about to use jQuery.ajax()?

```
 function Func1() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'MyWebService.asmx/Func1',
        success:Func1Success,
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error!');
        },
    });
    return false;
}
function Func1Success(output){
  $.ajax({
        url:'MyWebService.asmx/Func2',
        success:Func1SuccessToSuccess,
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error!');
        },
    });
}
function Func1SuccessToSuccess() {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can.

Just to give a suggestion/advice theoretically, you can have 1 local variable for the status response of the first web service method, you can have it as boolean, representing the success of the first invocation. Then sequentially, you can call the other web service method if your local variable matches your success condition.

What I provided is just an idea, for a more specific answer, I recommend you posting the actual code you're working on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using .cs files on your server and then calling them from android.
If this is what you are doing then there is one way to call a method on success of another method. Just make two .cs files say x and y and store it on your server. Then call one of them from android (x) and then make object of y in x and that will be all.
for eg. This is my one .cs file named abc.cs which il call from android.

```
 [WebMethod]
 public xyz IsLoggedIn()
 {
    xyz example = new xyz();
    //do something
    .
    .

    return example;
  }
```

now xyz.cs will be:

```
[WebMethod]
 public void onSuccessofIsLoggedIn()
 {
    //do something
    .
    .
  }
```

i hope this helps.... All this is just based on assumption though...please be clear about what you are using and we will be also more clear in our answers.